# How to put decal on object without raycaster?

Tags: three.js

All the demos I've seen are meant to be some kind of interactive, but I just need to place a couple of stickers on the object.

[Here is codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-thunder-gq8g8f?file=/src/index.ts)

My question is mostly code, but I have nothing more to add other than meaningless letters. I love you, wish you all the best, you are beautiful.

```js
import * as THREE from "three";
import { DecalGeometry } from "three/examples/jsm/geometries/DecalGeometry";

// Renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
camera.position.z = 10;

// Mesh
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: "lightblue",
  flatShading: true
});
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

// Decal
const decalPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
const decalRotation = new THREE.Euler();
const decalSize = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1);
const decalGeometry = new DecalGeometry(
  mesh,
  decalPosition,
  decalRotation,
  decalSize
);
const decalMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: "pink",
  polygonOffset: true,
  polygonOffsetFactor: -4
});
const decal = new THREE.Mesh(decalGeometry, decalMaterial);
scene.add(decal);

// Light
const dlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
dlight.position.z = 10;
scene.add(dlight);

// Resize
function resize() {
  const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;

  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(2, devicePixelRatio));
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
resize();

// Tick
function tick(t: number) {
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);

  mesh.rotation.y = t * 0.001;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

requestAnimationFrame(tick);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://github.com/spite/THREE.DecalGeometry/blob/master/demo/intersection.html) example and sort of understood how it works

[How to project decals](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/06/how-to-project-decals/)

```js
import * as THREE from "three";
import { DecalGeometry } from "three/examples/jsm/geometries/DecalGeometry";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

// Renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
camera.position.z = 10;

// Mesh
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1);
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: "lightblue"
});
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

// Decal parameters
const decalPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 1);
const decalRotation = new THREE.Euler(0);
const decalSize = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1);
const up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);

// Rotate the "projector"
let matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
matrix.lookAt(decalPosition, mesh.position, up);
matrix = matrix.extractRotation(matrix);
const dummy = new THREE.Object3D();
dummy.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(matrix);
decalRotation.set(dummy.rotation.x, dummy.rotation.y, dummy.rotation.z);

// Decal
const decalMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: "tomato",
  depthWrite: false,
  polygonOffset: true,
  polygonOffsetFactor: -4
});

const decalGeometry = new DecalGeometry(
  mesh,
  decalPosition,
  decalRotation,
  decalSize
);

const decal = new THREE.Mesh(decalGeometry, decalMaterial);
scene.add(decal);

// Decal Helper
const decalHelperGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(
  decalSize.x,
  decalSize.y,
  decalSize.z
);
const decalHelperMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ wireframe: true });
const decalHelper = new THREE.Mesh(decalHelperGeometry, decalHelperMaterial);
decalHelper.rotation.set(decalRotation.x, decalRotation.y, decalRotation.z);
decalHelper.position.copy(decalPosition);
scene.add(decalHelper);

// Light
const dlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
dlight.position.z = 10;
scene.add(dlight);

// Resize
function resize() {
  const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;

  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(2, devicePixelRatio));
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
resize();

new OrbitControls(camera, document.body);

// Tick
function tick(t: number) {
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

requestAnimationFrame(tick);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).